# Ant Build error Directory does not exist

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

I imported  project in eclipse and tried to run my build through Ant tool but console output always shows this error

```
D:\Schooooooool\akura-web\build.xml:132: Directory does not exist:  
D:\Schooooooool\akura-web\templib
```

Here is my build.xml

```
<property file="build.properties" />

<property name="akura.base.dir" location="${basedir}" />
<property name="src.dir" value="java/src" />
<property name="src.config.dir" value="java/config" />
<property name="build.dir" value="build" />
<property name="dist.dir" value="dist" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
<property name="temp.lib.dir" value="templib" />
<property name="common.api.dist.dir" value="../common-api/dist" />
<property name="common.api.lib.dir" value="../common-api/lib" />
<property name="common.util.dist.dir" value="../common-util/dist" />
<property name="common.util.lib.dir" value="../common-util/lib" />
<property name="common.service.dist.dir" value="../common-service/dist" />
<property name="common.service.lib.dir" value="../common-service/lib" />
<property name="auditing.service.dist.dir" value="../auditing-service/dist" />
<property name="auditing.service.lib.dir" value="../auditing-service/lib" />
<property name="staff.service.dist.dir" value="../staff-service/dist" />
<property name="student.service.dist.dir" value="../student-service/dist" />
<property name="school.service.dist.dir" value="../school-service/dist" />
<property name="reporting.service.dist.dir" value="../reporting-service/dist" />
<property name="attendance.service.dist.dir" value="../attendance-service/dist" />
<property name="attendance.service.lib.dir" value="../attendance-service/lib" />
<property name="src.build.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
<property name="framework.home" value="../" />
<property name="war.dir" value="war" />
<property name="name" value="akura" />
<property name="checkstyle.report.path" value="${basedir}/reports/checkstyle" />

<!-- Params for compiling the test cases -->
<property name="test.src.dir" value="test/src" />
<property name="test.config.dir" value="test/config" />
<property name="test.build.dir" value="${build.dir}/test-classes" />

<!-- properties related to, Emma and JUnit  -->
<property name="reports.dir" value="${basedir}/reports" />
<property name="emma.dir" value="${reports.dir}/emma" />
<property name="emma.html.dir" value="${emma.dir}/html" />
<property name="emma.classes.dir" value="${emma.dir}/classes" />
<property name="junit.report.dir" value="${reports.dir}/junit" />
<property name="junit.html.dir" value="${junit.report.dir}/html" />


<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${src.build.dir}" />
</path>

<!-- include the build of the common api -->
<macrodef name="commons">
    <attribute name="target" default="build" />
    <sequential>
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/common-api/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/common-api" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/common-util/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/common-util" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/common-service/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/common-service" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/auditing-service/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/auditing-service" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/staff-service/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/staff-service" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/student-service/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/student-service" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/school-service/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/school-service" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/reporting-service/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/reporting-service" target="@{target}" />
        <ant antfile="${framework.home}/attendance-service/build.xml" dir="${framework.home}/attendance-service" target="@{target}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="copyDependencies" description="copy the dependencies from common api project">
    <echo message="copy dependancies     --> akura web" />
    <commons target="build" />
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${common.api.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${common.api.lib.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${common.util.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${common.util.lib.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${common.service.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${common.service.lib.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${auditing.service.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${auditing.service.lib.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${staff.service.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${student.service.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${school.service.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${reporting.service.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${attendance.service.dist.dir}" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${temp.lib.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${attendance.service.lib.dir}" />
    </copy>

</target>


<!--Cleaning the  -->
<target name="clean" description="clean up">
    <echo message="clean     --> akura web" />
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${war.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${basedir}/reports" />

    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${temp.lib.dir}" excludes="**/.svn" />
    </delete>
</target>

<target name="cleanAll" depends="clean" description="clean up">
    <echo message="clean     --> akura projects" />
    <commons target="clean" />
</target>

<!-- Creates build, dist and other child directories with in them -->
<target name="prepare" depends="clean">
    <echo message="prepare     --> akura web" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${src.build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />

    <mkdir dir="${test.build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${emma.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${emma.html.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${emma.classes.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${junit.report.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${junit.html.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="build" depends="prepare,copyDependencies" description="Compile source code and create the jar file">
    <echo message="build     --> Build the application - akura web" />

    <javac destdir="${src.build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true" deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
        <src path="${src.dir}" />
        <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="buildwar" depends="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <mkdir dir="${war.dir}/jsp" />

    <copy todir="${war.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${akura.base.dir}/web" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" >
        <exclude name="emma_ant.jar"/>
        <exclude name="emma.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <fileset dir="${temp.lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
            <exclude name="junit.jar"/>
            <exclude name="emma_ant.jar"/>
            <exclude name="emma.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${temp.lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.properties" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <echo message="copying binaries to war" />
    <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${src.build.dir}" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${src.config.dir}" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate">
        <fileset dir="${temp.lib.dir}/hibernate" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/spring-beans">
        <fileset dir="${temp.lib.dir}/spring-beans" />
    </copy>

    <war destfile="${dist.dir}/${name}.war" webxml="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${war.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*" />
        </fileset>
    </war>

</target>

<target name="deploywar" depends="buildwar" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">

    <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir="${dist.dir}">
            <include name="*.war" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="checkstyle">
    <commons target="checkstyle" />
    <echo message="checkstyle     --> akura web" />
    <taskdef name="checkstyle" classpath="${basedir}/../common-config/code-quality-tools/checkstyle/bin/checkstyle-all-4.3.jar" classname="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.CheckStyleTask" />
    <property name="checkstyle.report.path" value="${basedir}/reports/checkstyle" />
    <property name="checkstyle.report.name" value="akura-web-checkstyle-report" />
    <property name="checkstyle.xml.report.file.name" value="${checkstyle.report.name}.xml" />
    <property name="checkstyle.html.report.file.name" value="${checkstyle.report.name}.html" />

    <mkdir dir="${checkstyle.report.path}" />
    <checkstyle config="${basedir}/../common-config/code-quality-config/SMSCheckStyle.xml" failOnViolation="false">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java" />
        <formatter type="xml" toFile="${checkstyle.report.path}/${checkstyle.xml.report.file.name}" />
    </checkstyle>

    <xslt in="${checkstyle.report.path}/${checkstyle.xml.report.file.name}" out="${checkstyle.report.path}/${checkstyle.html.report.file.name}" style="${basedir}/../common-config/code-quality-tools/checkstyle/checkstyle-html.xsl" />
</target>

<!-- Compile the JUnit test classes -->
<target name="test" depends="build">
    <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.build.dir}" debug="true">
        <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
    </javac>

    <!-- Begin emma block -->
    <taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="master-classpath" />

    <!-- Instrument the .class files. -->
    <emma enabled="true">
        <instr instrpath="${src.build.dir}" destdir="${emma.classes.dir}" metadatafile="${emma.dir}/metadata.emma" merge="true" mode="overwrite">
        </instr>
    </emma>

    <!-- End emma block -->

    <!-- Run JUnit Test Cases -->
    <junit printsummary="true" fork="yes">
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${junit.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java" excludes="**/BaseWebTest.java" />
        </batchtest>

        <classpath>
            <path refid="master-classpath" />
            <path path="${test.build.dir}" />
            <path path="${src.config.dir}" />
            <path path="${temp.lib.dir}" />
        </classpath>

        <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${emma.dir}/coverage.emma" />
        <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=true" />
    </junit>

    <!-- Generates HTML reports for the test -->

    <junitreport todir="${junit.report.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.report.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.html.dir}" />

    </junitreport>

    <!-- Begin emma block -->
    <!-- Generate Emma reports. -->
    <emma enabled="true">
        <report sourcepath="${src.dir}" depth="method">
            <infileset dir="${emma.dir}">
                <include name="*.emma" />
                <include name="*.ec" />
            </infileset>

            <xml outfile="${emma.dir}/coverage.xml" />
            <html outfile="${emma.html.dir}/index.html" />
        </report>
    </emma>

    <!-- End emma block -->

</target>
```

This is my project structure Akura-wed is basedir
[Project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Rnh.png)

Ant console after running deploywar

> Buildfile: D:\Schooooooool\akura-web\build.xml clean:
>        [echo] clean     --> akura web

BUILD FAILED

> D:\Schooooooool\akura-web\build.xml:132: Directory does not exist:
>   D:\Schooooooool\akura-web\templib

Comment: What precisely is the question? *Does* the directory actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a problem in the arguments being passed to the script. Check the configuration for running the tool to see what arguments are being passed to the script.

Look in 'Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations' and look it the 'Ant Build' section.